# How to set tempLocation for Custom Dataflow Template?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

How should I set tempLocation for Custom Dataflow Pipeline?

- I tired to set it when uploading my Dataflow Template to Bucket with

  `--tempLocation={my-location}`
- I tried to set it as parameter when starting Custom Dataflow Template from UI
- I tried to overwrite it in my PipelineOptions like:

  `options.setTempLocation({my-location});`

In all of those cases it was shown as `-` in Dataflow UI.

Comment: Hey Magda, do you still have this problem? I set my tempLocation using options.setTempLocation(tmpLoc) and it updates in the UI. Are you sure your "my-location" variable is set? Could it be that you're setting it mid pipeline execution and it's too late? It could also be that you're overwriting or setting it to default somewhere.
I've also used --tempLocation={myLoc} successfully before. Are your temp files written to their correct destination (maybe a UI bug)?

Comment: Did you have a specific error? Or did you pipeline run normally? There could just be an issue displaying the parameter in the UI, but it may be functioning properly. If you would like the support team to look into this then please file a support ticket
cloud.google.com/support